# Is it possible to move even with immutable borrows?

Tags: rust

```
use std::marker;
use std::ops;
pub struct Shared<'r, T: 'r> {
    data: *mut T,
    _pd: marker::PhantomData<&'r T>,
}

impl<'r, T> Shared<'r, T> {
    pub fn new(value: T) -> Shared<'r, T> {
        let boxed = Box::new(value);
        Shared {
            data: Box::into_raw(boxed),
            _pd: marker::PhantomData,
        }
    }

    pub fn as_ref(&self) -> SharedRef<'r, T> {
        SharedRef {
            data: self.data,
            _pd: marker::PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<'r, T> ops::Deref for Shared<'r, T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        unsafe { &*self.data }
    }
}

pub struct SharedRef<'r, T: 'r> {
    data: *mut T,
    _pd: marker::PhantomData<&'r T>,
}

impl<'r, T> ops::Deref for SharedRef<'r, T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        unsafe { &*self.data }
    }
}

impl<'r, T> Drop for Shared<'r, T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            Box::from_raw(self.data);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = Shared::new(42);
    let s_ref = s.as_ref();
    {
        let s1 = s;
    }
    // lifetime should end here
    println!("{}", *s_ref);
}
```

What I wanted to express was a mix between a `Box` and an `Arc`. A uniquely owned pointer that is also capable of giving out references.

The problem is that I want to be able to move `Shared` around even if there are currently immutable borrows to it. It should be legal in this scenario because it is heap allocated.

The problem is that I have no idea how to express this.

```
fn main() {
    let s = Shared::new(42);
    let s_ref = s.as_ref();
    {
        let s1 = s;
    }
    // lifetime should end here
    println!("{}", *s_ref);
}
```

Here I move `s` into a scope with "less" lifetime than it had before. But now after I have moved `s` into `s1`, `s_ref` should not be accessible anymore. So what I want to say is that it is okay to move a `Shared` if the lifetime does not get smaller.

Can this be expressed in Rust?

Comment: Have you seen [owning-ref](https://github.com/Kimundi/owning-ref-rs)?

Comment: The `PhantomData` in `Shared` does not look right, `Shared` *owns* its item.

Comment: @Shepmaster I haven't but I am not sure if it would help me. I made a more specific question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079922/is-it-possible-to-have-internal-pointers-without-using-an-arc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason Rust allows you to move out of the `Shared` is that you haven't tied the lifetime of the returned `SharedRef` to it:

```
pub fn as_ref(&self) -> SharedRef<'r, T> {
    SharedRef {
        data: self.data,
        _pd: marker::PhantomData,
    }
}
```

Annotating the `&self` fixes that:

```
pub fn as_ref(&'r self) -> SharedRef<'r, T> { .. }
```

My current understanding is that the key difference here is that this says that the lifetime of the `SharedRef` now matches the lifetime of the *borrow* of `self`, keeping the borrow alive.  Indeed it doesn't have to be the same lifetime (`'r`) as in the `Shared`; it works with a new lifetime just for the borrow/return:

```
pub fn as_ref<'b>(&'b self) -> SharedRef<'b, T> { .. }
```

This also disallows the move.

As for the bonus part of the question, where you want to allow moving as long as it's to something with a long enough lifetime, I think the answer is no.  The only way I know to stop something being moved at all is to borrow it, and that stops any move.