# Is it possible to have `internal pointers` without using an `Arc`?

Tags: rust

```
struct Device;

struct CommandBuffer {
    device: &Device,
    // ...
}

// Does not work because Rust does not allow internal pointers
struct Something {
    device: Device,
    command_buffer: CommandBuffer,
}
```

One solution would be to use an `Arc`

```
struct CommandBuffer {
    device: Arc<Device>,
    // ...
}
struct Something {
    device: Arc<Device>,
    command_buffer: CommandBuffer,
}
```

The downside of an `Arc` is indirection, an atomic counter and the possibility of escaping the scope and keeping the `Device` alive.

Now I don't think that you can work around the one level of indirection in Rust but could it be possible to create something between a `Box` and an `Arc`?

```
struct CommandBuffer {
    device: BoxRef<Device>,
    // ...
}
struct Something {
    device: Box<Device>,
    command_buffer: CommandBuffer,
}
```

The main problem that I had while trying to implement `BoxRef` was that I need to be able to move a `Box` even if there are currently borrows to it. That should technically be safe because of the level of indirection, but I don't think that this can currently be expressed in Rust.

```
let boxed_device = Box::new(device);
let device_ref = boxed_device.boxed_ref();

// Owner of the reference should be allowed to move
Something{device: boxed_device, CommandBuffer{device: device_ref}}
```

1. Could `BoxRef` be implemented? I had a quick look at
   [owning_ref](http://kimundi.github.io/owning-ref-rs/owning_ref/index.html)
   but it doesn't seem to solve the problem that I have.
2. What other options do I have to express "internal pointers" in Rust?

Comment: I could be wrong but it sounds like you're after a `RefCell` perhaps?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead A `RefCell` also can not be moved when there are active borrows, or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Apologies I think I misunderstood yours - it was late at night. Without the use of `unsafe` .. as far as I am aware `Arc` and/or `Rc` with a custom wrapper would be the only way to do this.

Comment: I don't understand why you think you ought to be able to move a `Box` with outstanding borrows.  The reason that isn't allowed is that the new owner will control when the `Box` is dropped, which is also when the memory gets freed. Can you elaborate on why your scenario is sound?

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
struct Device;

struct CommandBuffer<'a> {
    device: &'a Device, // ...
}

struct Something<'a> {
    device: &'a Device,
    command_buffer: CommandBuffer<'a>,
}

fn main() {

    let dev = Device;

    let smth = Something {
        device: &dev,
        command_buffer: CommandBuffer { device: &dev },
    };
}
```

You should not worry about `Arc` performance *that* much.

The possibility of escaping the scope could be easily dealt with by just writing a newtype that keeps the `Arc` private, and only implements `Deref` to `&T` without `Clone`.